# How can I reuse my code on each click of Floating Action Button in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Here is my code which I used to print text_switch_on and text_switch_off on each click of floatingActionButton but after running my application it stopped working and black screen showed up.

```
 while(true) {
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (floatingActionButton.isEnabled()) {
                button_switch_on_off.text = getString(R.string.text_switch_off)
            } else {
                button_switch_on_off.text = getString(R.string.text_switch_on)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while(true)` means “do this repeatedly, forever”. And what it’s doing is setting copies of the same button listener on the button over and over, and preventing the app from being able to do anything else, like draw the UI to the screen. There’s no reason to be doing this inside a loop. Set the listener only once. It will be called on every future button press.

Comment: I tried without while(true) but it only works for one time, on second click text does not change.

Comment: @AlyanAhmed it happens because your condition for changing text is not satisfied. I assume your button is being enabled all the time, therefore it never reaches the condition where "text_switch_on" is being used

Comment: Here is my code for button, please help me what is need to be modified.
`<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/md_black_1000"
        app:fabCustomSize="150dp"
        app:maxImageSize="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_power_switch" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test text changing like this:

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
    if (button_switch_on_off.text == getString(R.string.text_switch_off)) {
        button_switch_on_off.text = getString(R.string.text_switch_on)
    } else {
        button_switch_on_off.text = getString(R.string.text_switch_off)
    }
}
```

However, I assume you should provide yourself with logic, when your button enters `disabled` state, whereas your former logic (without `while(true)`) will work fine as well